# Django Downloading a media file using XHR gives CORS error

Tags: django

I have a project where the admin upload FBX files, 
These FBX files are fetched through an XHR call and loaded to Threejs.

Django Set-up.

Requirement.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0.2
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
django-filter==2.2.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
Markdown==3.1.1
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

URLS

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('fbx/', include('fbx.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Upload model

```
from django.db import models

class Fbx(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fbx = models.FileField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    normals = models.FileField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    bump = models.FileField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    texture = models.FileField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

IMPORTS and MIDDLEWARES

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'fbx.apps.FbxConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

I have no issues with upload, everything works fine.

I'm using Threejs FBXloader to download the FBX. This is an XHR call. 
This call fails. But if I put the same link on the browser it works fine.

The XHR call to this file http://XXXX/media/correction_1.fbx fails. 
But works when you put it in browser.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Fails how? Do you have an error message, a traceback, anything? What do your views looks like?

Comment: @TomCarrick I'm getting a CORS error, I have CORS error only for static files.
all the other API's work

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://xxx/media/correction_1.fbx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: var request = new Request('http://xxx/media/correction_1.fbx');
fetch(request).then(function(e) { console.log(e)/* handle response */ });

Comment: CORS works for regular API calls but fails for media files

Comment: `xxx` is what? Some other not-localhost host? And its CORS configuration is what…?

Comment: Start with moving corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware above the django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware in settings.MIDDLEWARE, so that the django middleware does not overwrite django-cors-headers responses.

Comment: @deceze
there are two XHR calls
1) http://example.com/get-active-fbx    -- works without any cors issue. 
2) http://example.com/media/fbxname.fbx  --- does not work. 

Both the above api's are being called from
http://example.com:81/

First API fetches the details for the second API. 
the second XHR is a direct link to a file, it has CORS error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not serve the media files through the middleware stack, so any attempts to inject headers are pointless. You need to enable the CORS in the apache. 
This change in the virutal host did it for me.

```
Alias /media/ /**<path to media>**/media/
<Directory /**<path to media>**/media>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you can not access the virutal host it is possible to do the change in the .htaccess 
https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: I am using python anyhere where do i add these lines ?

Comment: httpd.conf this is the configuration of the domain in the apache. If you are using shared hosting you may need to contact your administrator